# Slow performance when using OFFSET/FETCH with Fulltext in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a database-size pagination of query results. As SQL Server 2012 offers `OFFSET/FETCH`, I'm using it. But after I add the statement to my query, it takes 10 times longer.

The queries:

```
SELECT 
    p.ShopId, 
    count(1) as ProductsQuantity, 
    MIN(LastPrice) as MinPrice, 
    MAX(LastPrice) as MaxPrice
FROM Product2 p WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN
   CONTAINSTABLE(Product2, ProductName, 'czarny') AS KEY_TBL
ON KEY_TBL.[key]=p.Id
WHERE 
    (p.LastStatus > 0 OR p.LastStatus = -1) 
GROUP BY p.ShopId
ORDER BY p.ShopId asc



SELECT 
    p.ShopId, 
    count(1) as ProductsQuantity, 
    MIN(LastPrice) as MinPrice, 
    MAX(LastPrice) as MaxPrice
FROM Product2 p WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN
   CONTAINSTABLE(Product2, ProductName, 'czarny') AS KEY_TBL
ON KEY_TBL.[key]=p.Id
WHERE 
    (p.LastStatus > 0 OR p.LastStatus = -1)   
GROUP BY p.ShopId
ORDER BY p.ShopId asc
OFFSET  10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

First query returns results in 3 seconds, the second one in 47 seconds. Execution plan are different, and the second's cost is evaluated only as 7%, what totally makes no sense to me:

[image: Execution plan]

I need help how to improve performance of the pagination.

Comment: +1 to this question, just out of the factyou added an explain plan without anyone aksing for it and this is actually an issue pagination in T-SQL encounters quite often

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to advise without having your schema and data in hands. There is at least one thing that you should be able to do with those 3 sec. for first query and 47 sec. for second, which is put results of the first query into temporary table and then use it for `order by ... offset fetch next`:

```
create table #tmp (Id int not NULL, Quantity int, MinPrice decimal(10,4), MaxPrice decimal(10,4), primary key clustered (Id))

insert into #tmp
SELECT 
    p.ShopId, 
    count(1) as ProductsQuantity, 
    MIN(LastPrice) as MinPrice, 
    MAX(LastPrice) as MaxPrice
FROM Product2 p WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN
   CONTAINSTABLE(Product2, ProductName, 'czarny') AS KEY_TBL
ON KEY_TBL.[key]=p.Id
WHERE 
    (p.LastStatus > 0 OR p.LastStatus = -1) 
GROUP BY p.ShopId

select ShopId, ProductsQuantity, MinPrice, MaxPrice
from #tmp
ORDER BY ShopId asc
OFFSET  10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: your solution works well, same speed as returning result without pagination.

Comment: Just for others: i've found older pagination methods for SQL Server, as described here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2696/comparing-performance-for-different-sql-server-paging-methods/  

I've tested them, and the results are:  
1. SQL 2000 method (temporary table with identity): 32 seconds  
2. SQL 2005 method (CTE with ROW_NUMBER()): 47 second  

So using FETCH NEXT without temp table is slowest solution of all.

Comment: i don't consider this a proper solution as you are still joining with ALL the results of the containstable and then taking and skipping the rows. But the result of the fulltext search is still first going to get all results, and then you are cutting off these results. I know that containstable has a way to take the top ones only by adding 'czarny', 10), but i haven't figured out how to skip this